# My WordPress Dashboard Problems left side to right side

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins, dashboard

My WordPress dashboard isn't left site. It's right site. My site also seam. Please give me a solution.

My site : http://www.mashovirali.co.il/

Dashboard Screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/132964227/screenshot_29.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this has happened is because you are using a Hebrew language pack. Hebrew is a right to left language, unlike english with is left to right.

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation to unset the RTL feature. Its down to the locale that WP is setup.

Also you would want to keep the RTL feature within any languages that are RTL so that any users of the system will understand it. A left aligned RTL language doesnt make much sense.